# How do I build/debug the current open .cpp file in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: c++, g++, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to set up Visual Studio Code with a debug task that compiles and debugs the current open .cpp file? I'm on macOS Sierra 10.12.6.

The standard documentation explains creating a task that compiles a specific .cpp file to a.out and modifying the launch.json to run that as a preLaunchTask, but then I have to create a new task for each .cpp file I create. It gets a bit tedious as I'm learning C++ and writing many small example programs.

Somebody asked a similar question here but this solution only seems to compile the first .cpp it encounters. If it compiled all .cpp files, it would probably help for me.

[How do I set up VSCode to compile C++ code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30269449/how-do-i-set-up-vscode-to-compile-c-code)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like the answer to [this SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45679035/build-currently-opened-file-in-visual-studio-code).

One way to avoid creating separate build tasks for each file (as long as the language you are using is the same) is to use the `${file}` keyword instead of the filename in the build task in `tasks.json`, which will build the file you currently have open in VS Code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I made the change and it worked perfectly.

For more context, there are examples [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/tasks#_operating-system-specific-properties), one of which includes the usage of `${file}`:

Comment: You are welcome, @NathanPerkins, Please accept my answer and upvote it if it is satisfactory.